# Java input dialog tooltip and pasting option?

Tags: java, swing, tooltip, textfield, joptionpane

Is there a nice way in Java to set a tooltip for the input dialog's textfield?

For example:

`String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter input:");`

Is it also possible to have a right click paste option for this textfield?

Thank-you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's possible to add a tooltip through that static method. I suggest you to create an JOptionPane instance of your own, find the JTextField and set it's tooltip.

```
public class Main {

    public static List<Component> getAllComponents(final Container c) {
        Component[] comps = c.getComponents();
        List<Component> compList = new ArrayList<Component>();
        for (Component comp : comps) {
            compList.add(comp);
            if (comp instanceof Container)
                compList.addAll(getAllComponents((Container) comp));
        }
        return compList;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JOptionPane optionPane = new JOptionPane();
        optionPane.setMessage("What's your name?");
        optionPane.setMessageType(JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
        optionPane.setWantsInput(true);
        JDialog dialog = optionPane.createDialog("Simple Question");
        for (Component c : getAllComponents(dialog)) {
         if (c instanceof JTextField) {
             c.setToolTipText("I'm a tooltip!");
         }
        }
        dialog.setVisible(true);
        dialog.dispose();
    }
}
```

Right click and paste works by default.

Comment: You should add `dialog.dispose()` after `setVisible` to release resources that will otherwise keep the program running forever. (: